# What's the function of "how" in "This is how they lived"?

Tags: clauses, parts-of-speech

> This is **how they lived**.

In the sentence above, what function does *how* have? Complements, interrogatives, content clauses, etc. I looked up on CGEL, but I’ve not found explanations for the example. It seems like ‘*how they lived*’ makes a complement from ‘*they lived how*’; ‘*how*’ is a manner adjunct, or ascriptive/descriptive adjuct. And from any construction pattern, ‘*how*’ is shifted forward to make the clause, *they lived how*, the complement of *is*.

How should I understand the *how* clause?

Comment: *How they lived* is a fused relative clause, like *who they were* or *what they did*. *How* here acts as a pro-adverbial, whose referent is an adverb or preposition phrase of manner: *They lived extravagantly* or *They lived in this manner*.

Comment: Similar would be "This is *the way* they lived."

Comment: Consider the question form that the statement would answer: "How did they live? This is how they lived." --- "How should I understand the *how* clause? **This is how you should understand the *how* clause.**"

Comment: A subordinate expression that has the word "how" as its leading word can often be hard to identify at first. For your example, it seems that there are three potential possibilities: ***open interrogative content clause, exclamative content clause, fused relative (NP).*** You'll probably want to look up the word "how" for all three types of constructions (e.g. page 1075, text under [22] for the fused-relative).

Comment: @F.E. Yes, that’s the very reason I become confused whenever I come across how clauses. In CGEL page 1077, [29 iii] _“That’s not how to do it,”_ they say _“the infinitival of ‘how to do it’ is not possible in fused relatives._ (same page, 9th line from bottom)” Does this apply to all the infinitivals or just to this one?

Comment: Yes, that is an interrogative. The word "how" is extremely restricted in uses as a fused-relative. Notice how their ***interrogative*** example [29.iii] *"That's who I meant"* is quite similar to your example of *"This is how they lived"*. Notice how their structures sorta parallel each other. (Also, notice that these are *specifying "be" constructions*.)

Comment: Also, notice that ***interrogative*** example [29.iv] *"He's not who she thinks he is"* is quite similar to your example in another thread of yours "evidence that *somebody is who they say that they are*".

Comment: Does this need to go to EL&U? It seems a bit too complex for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did they run? You are asking in what way/manner they performed the action of the *verb*; such a word is an *adverb*: They ran *quickly*. If a number of words: *at top speed/as fast as they could*, it is an adverbial phrase/clause. In 'How did they run?' it is an interrogative adverb; in 'This is how they ran', it is a relative adverb.